# mvn tomcat:run mixes up with application URI

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat, cloudbees

I get different behaviours regarding the starting url in jsp files when I deploy the application or when I test it using `mvn tomcat:run`

Here is the jsp code that works fine in deploying the application on cloudbees

```
    <form method="post" action="/import" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

whereas when I use `mvn tomcat:run` I need to add the maven artifact Id as the start of the url for the action part of the form :

```
    <form method="post" action="my-application/import" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Any help on what kind of configuration parameters I should look at for that would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled under the maven tomcat plugin section in the pom.xml through the path parameter as stated in [This documentation link](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Setting the path at / will ensure you have the same behaviour of urls when you try on your PC with mvn tomcat7:run and after deployment on cloudbees. Here is the pom.xml excerpt :

```
<build>
       <plugins>
            ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```